# pgadmin4 unable to connect to server,FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

i tried to config postgresql to be able to connect to pgadmin4 "remotely"
So i installed postgresql version 13 in the server ,and i tried to access it via my laptop.

But why do i always get an error , i just changed the password and i enter the username and password in the pgadmin4 ,it still says password authentication.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKsdv.png)

this is my pghba.conf file.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0           trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

this is my postgesql.conf file

```
listen_addresses = '*'
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5434             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql, /tmp'  # comma-separated list of directories
                    # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                    # (change requires restart)

# - TCP settings -
# see "man tcp" for details

#tcp_keepalives_idle = 0        # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_interval = 0        # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_count = 0       # TCP_KEEPCNT;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_user_timeout = 0           # TCP_USER_TIMEOUT, in milliseconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default

# - Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min      # 1s-600s
password_encryption = scram-sha-256     # md5 or scram-sha-256
#db_user_namespace = off

# GSSAPI using Kerberos
#krb_server_keyfile = 'FILE:${sysconfdir}/krb5.keytab'
#krb_caseins_users = off
```

and still i don't know why, maybe someone experienced the same ? or have any idea?
fyi : i open the pgadmin4 application and the url going to this :http://127.0.0.1:60888/browser/

[this is my pgadmin4 in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5vO6.png)

Comment: The pg_hba you show will never attempt password authentication, so it cannot fail at it.  It seems like you are not trying to connect to the server you think you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after changing in the pg_hba.conf

from

```
local   all             all                                     trust
```

to become

```
host   all             all                                     trust
```

Now it works like a charm.. Thankyou everyone! :)

Answer (score 10):

On image1 you changed the password for Postgres **linux user**, not for Postgres  database user. Try next:

```sh
sudo -u postgres psql postgres # connect to Postgres
\password postgres # change password postgres user
\q # quite from Postgres shell
```

Then try to connect to Postgres again.

Would be helpful: https://docs.boundlessgeo.com/suite/1.1.1/dataadmin/pgGettingStarted/firstconnect.html

Comment: Hello thanks for answering, i still got the same error though ,i tried your method, tried to test connection with psql -U postgres -W ,and it works

Comment: i mean the connection was successful , but in pgadmin web browser(my laptop) didn't works

Comment: Hello folks. I had same issue. My environment: platform = Linux POP OS, PostgreSQL version = psql (15.2 (Ubuntu 15.2-1.pgdg22.04+1).  Your solution solved my problem.  Prior, one line from pg_hba.conf in /etc/postgresql/15/main directory was modified as follows: 

As Found
````local  all  all  peer ````
    
As Changed 

```` local  all  all  trust````


Next. in root directory the postgresql service was restarted  with the following command:

````sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start ````